# Xamarin Android Facebook share button disabled

Tags: facebook, xamarin.android

Hope You're all ok.
I have a simple xamarin android application, and trying to integrate facebook share button in it.
I've done all by docs, and other tutorials. App is registered in Facebook.
But the button is showing gray in app, it's disabled. 
I don't know what's the problem. 
Testing it in Nexus 5, with Android M 6.0.1.

Thanks.

Little update on what I've done so far.

Manifest File

**Manifest File**

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id" />
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" 
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation" 
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" 
              android:label="@string/ApplicationName" />
        <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider266540057101076" android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" android:exported="true" />
```

**Activity file code snippet**

```
<com.facebook.share.widget.ShareButton
      android:id="@+id/fShareButton"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

**And finally controller.**

```
private ShareButton fShareButton;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getKeyHashes();
    FacebookSdk.SdkInitialize(ApplicationContext);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.details);
    fShareButton = FindViewById<ShareButton>(Resource.Id.fShareButton);
    fShareButton.Click += FShareButton_Click;
    ..........
 }

private void FShareButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    #region Facebook Share Button
    View v1 = Window.DecorView.RootView;
    v1.DrawingCacheEnabled = true;

    Android.Graphics.Bitmap bitmap = Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CreateBitmap(v1.GetDrawingCache(true));

    var photoBuilder = new SharePhoto.Builder();
    photoBuilder.SetBitmap(bitmap);
    var photo = photoBuilder.Build().JavaCast<SharePhoto>();

    var photos = new List<SharePhoto>();
    photos.Add(photo);

    SharePhotoContent photoContent = new SharePhotoContent.Builder().SetPhotos(photos).Build();
    fShareButton.ShareContent = photoContent;
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Could you please let us know what have you tried so far? Probably through code snippet? We can not help you if we do not know what you have tried

Comment: Thanks @DarrenChristopher for Your response. I've almost tried everything, every topic , every fix in stackoverflow and other forums. 
I can show You the code snippets , where I'm trying to initialize facebook button. Will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

You must set callbackManager and fill ShareContent property in ShareButton, in my example I use ShareLinkContent for the content, but there are other options like "ShareMediaContent", "SharePhotContent", etc., you can get more explanaition about this in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android/?locale=en_US :

```
fShareButton = FindViewById<ShareButton>(Resource.Id.fShareButton);
            callbackManager = CallbackManagerFactory.Create();
            fShareButton.RegisterCallback(callbackManager, this);
            var content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder();
            content.SetContentUrl(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("https://www.mivinco.com/linkapp_an9.html"));
            var hashtag = new ShareHashtag.Builder();
            hashtag.SetHashtag("#porqueTuExperienciaCuenta");
            content.SetShareHashtag((ShareHashtag)hashtag.Build());
            fShareButton.ShareContent = content.Build();
```

Also, you should implement IFacebookCallback interface in your activity:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.OnActivityResult(requestCode, (int)resultCode, data);
    }
```

It works fine in my Android app.  Let me know if it works fine in your app too.